# How to convert Ajax escape Function result char convert to CHAR

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I got a situation just to include the special character which is `'` Single Quote in an input elements of html.

Iv'e tried to use `escape` Function of Ajax like `escape('''sampledata)` which doing well.

As a Result:

The Single Quote `'` turns to `%27`.

As investigating this character `%27` Iv'e tried to use:

```
char c=   Convert.ToChar(27)
```

In my Home Controller.

Unfortunately the char `c` value become a character of its look like a `small backward arrow` which is i did not expect.

Is it possible to convert this char `%27` to a character of `'` which a single quote character?

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a more complete example code of what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks @Jasen, I guess is that all about..  just a escape function using ajax like `escape('''sample text from input file)` and i need all the `'` single qoute character to back as is but not `%27`.

Comment: The reason why i need to use the escape function because the ajax data returns an error of this `'` single quote character.